# Align text on two different lines using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm creating a PDF using iText and want to vertically align text in two paragraphs. I'm using tab characters to try and align the "1" and the "2":

```
document.add(new Paragraph("Example"+"\t\t\t1"));
document.add(new Phrase("Hello World JAVA"+"\t\t\t2"));
```

Here is a screenshot of how the resulting PDF looks:

[image: PDF example]

Can anyone suggest a better way to align text? Clearly tabs are not working how I expected. What I'm looking for is this:

```
Example           1
Hello World JAVA  2
```

Comment: Please be clean and neat in questioning..

Comment: It is very difficult to understand your question. Can you try and [explain it again](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13418087/edit), with different wording?

Comment: While I don't understand what exactly you want, you seem to search a way to make the strings you add to the document appear in certain positions. In that case the chapter 2 "Using iText’s basic building blocks" of iText in Action, 2ns edition, might be of help for you. This chapter can be downloaded as a sample of the book [here](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter2.pdf).

Comment: I understand your first question to mean "*How can I add 'Hello World JAVA' so that it's on the same line as 'Example' and not in a new paragraph*". Your second question seems to be "*How can I align the '1' and the '2' in my example so that it gives the appearance of being in a table*". Surely there is no answer that can satisfy both requirements?

Comment: @Duncan Jones : Yes, that's what i mean

Comment: @user1815938 Do you see why there cannot be one answer to solve both problems? If you move "Hello World JAVA" onto the same line as "Example", you cannot align the "1" and the "2"?

Comment: @Duncan Jones : Ok, i understand. How to resolve the problem number 2. because using \ t then it depends on the sentence before (long and short), so how to make the previous sentence had no effect, so the second column in the first row and the second row can be aligned??

Comment: @user1815938 I've taken the liberty of completely re-writing your question based on what you appear to want. If I've made a mistake, please feel free to roll-back my edits (or correct what I've done).

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered how to upvote comments, and I upvoted mkl's remark because the answer can indeed by found in http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter2.pdf of which I'm the author.

Search the PDF for **TAB CHUNKS**. Note that the `'\t'` character has no meaning in a PDF.